# popualte textbox from values on screen with javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts

how can I use the values from the code below:

```
 <html:select property="state" > 

 <html:option value="0">Select State</html:option> 

 <html:optionsCollection name="InputForm" property="stateList" label="label" value="value" /> 

 </html:select>
```

to populate a textbox with whatever the selected value is for the state with a javascript onchange event? for example if texas is the selected state I want Texas to be written in the textbox and if I change the value to Colorado I would like Colorado and Texas to both show in the textbox. I am currently getting an undefined value in the textbox. I am using the following javascript code:

```
   function displayState(obj, state) {
    var theId = obj.id.substring(obj.id.indexOf('_') + 1);        
    var text = document.getElementById('text' + '_' + theId);
    var textVal = text.value;

    var stateSelect = document.getElementById('stateCode' + '_' + theId);
    var stateSelectStr = new String(stateSelect.value);
    var stateSelectSplit = stateSelectStr.split(',');
    var stateSelectValue = stateSelectSplit[0];
    var stateSelectLabel = stateSelectSplit[1];

    if (stateSelectValue == '51') {
            stateSelectLabel = '';
    }
    if (stateSelectValue != '00') {
            textVal = textVal != '' ? eval('text.value=\'' + textVal + ', '
                            + stateSelectLabel + '\'')
                            : eval('text.value=\'' + stateSelectLabel + '\'');
    }

  }
```

Comment: i am using a jsp with struts tags

Comment: here is a better example of what I would like to do: http://homepage.ntlworld.com/kayseycarvey/jss3p10.html?s1=Opera&Submit=Get+Selected+Items except i would like to use a dropdown menu and instead of a popup have the text appear in a textfield

Answer (score 0):

First off, start using jQuery (or equivalent), it will make your life *much* easier. Second, why are you using eval? You already have the text element; just build the appropriate string and set the value. [See here for an example.](http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-value.phtml)

But again, using something like jQuery makes this laughably easy--I can't recommend using a library for simple DOM manipulation like this.

[See here for a comparison between raw JS and JQ.](http://jsfiddle.net/KHnj8/)